# Refresh Fragments - android

Tags: android, fragment

I do have two fragments in my App

Fragment One : download Image to my fragment two grideView

Fragment two : show the image that been downloaded from fragment one

The thing is when I download the image and switch to the second Fragment tab , nothing show up but when I restart the App I can see the image is downloaded inside my second fragment

I don't want this to be happen , I want the new images appear in the second fragment after downloading it in the same time . Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

I just need to call use onResume in the Fragments class and it will refresh it.